# In Modern Warfare 2, are there any achievements in the museum?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I've completed Modern Warfare 2 and gotten bored of online multiplayer play. (I have a lag problem)

Are there any achievements to be won in the museum level? I want to get them all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there are no achievements for that level.

There is an easter egg where you can walk over to one of the museum desks that has a button. Pressing the button makes the characters come alive and try to kill you.

If you want to complete the achievements, you can find a complete list [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/951944-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2/cheats). If you need help, you can also consult the [achievement guide.](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/951944-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2/faqs/58353)

Comment: Is that an easter egg? Aren't you supposed to kill those characters to complete the museum stage?

Comment: @Lazer, I believe it is considered one. Plus, you don't really complete the museum level either. Killing them is purely for fun.

Comment: It's a shame you can't *prekill* them :P